# find the combination of records that sum up to given limits

Tags: algorithm, combinations

Given the set of records that contain only integer elements find the (one or all) combinations of records that sum up to given limits. For example if have records that represent fruits and their characteristics(elements) are vitamins A, B and C

```
Apple - A=10, B=5, C=15
Orange - A=1, B=20, C=14
Banana - A=4, B=9, C=5
```

And the limits are

```
For A - 13 to 15
For B - 10 to 15
For C - 20 to 25
```

In this case the combination that fulfill the limits would be Apple and Banana. Is there an algorithm that works better than brute force?

Answer (score 0):

This is an integer linear program (with constant objective function).

Solving problems like this is NP, but there are solvers that can solve practical problems (even quite large ones) efficiently.

One such solver is [GLPK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Linear_Programming_Kit).

Finding algorithms to solve ILPs efficiently is an active research area. There's some information on the wikipedia page for [Integer Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming).